# aggregate ‘arcball arcball’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Tags: c++, struct, include, extern

I'm having a bit of a problem on the following files:

i have the arcball struct on this file:

```
#ifndef ARCBALL_H_
#define ARCBALL_H_

#include "ex1.h"

...

extern struct arcball{
    float radius;
    int x,y;
}arcball;

...

#endif /* ARCBALL_H_ */
```

and I have the following ex1.h file which includes the arcball.h file:

```
#ifndef __EX1_H__
#define __EX1_H__


////////////////////////////
// Project Includes         
////////////////////////////

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "arcball.h"


////////////////////////////
// OpenMesh Includes        
////////////////////////////

#include "OpenMesh/Core/IO/MeshIO.hh"
#include "OpenMesh/Core/Mesh/PolyMesh_ArrayKernelT.hh"

////////////////////////////
// GL Includes              
////////////////////////////

#include "GLee.h"
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

...

struct arcball arcball;
#endif
```

I have to include the ex1.h header since the ex1.h holds includes for glut functions I 
use in the arcball.cpp file as well.
and I have to use the arcball.h header in order to use the functions and the struct 
defines on that file.

The error I get is the following:

```
In file included from arcball.h:11:0,
                 from arcball.cpp:8:
ex1.h:120:16: error: aggregate ‘arcball arcball’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
make: *** [ex1] Error 1
```

I don't understand why it is an incomplete type, since I included arcball.h file

Is this an mutual inclusion issue or a struct definition/usage issue?
And how can it be resolved?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that declaring a variable which has the same name as its type's name is a particularly good idea. Also, if this is C++ and not C, don't tag it as C.

Comment: it's a global variable and its not typedef so using arcball will simply call the arcball variable... there is no explicit c++ usage over here, this can be used and compiled like a c code.

Comment: fine, but note that only one of the C or C++ tags should be present - they're not the same language, not even interchangeable.

Comment: but syntax wise it is the same,at least in the presented code.
i could use some help here... from c++/c people

Comment: @Itzik984: C or C++. Pick one please.

Comment: really dont understand why it is not important for the question (both c/c++ people can help here), but c tag is off. FYI @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @Itzik984: You've decided that the answer must be the same for either language, but you're not in a position to know that. They are separate languages with different semantics, and you're only using one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The two `.h` files include each other, causing much of the confusion.  That's a terribly bad idea, as the `#ifdef` around will have different effects depending on which file is included first: in this case, arcball.h -> ex1.h -> arcball.h-but-really-nothing-because-of-the-#ifdef.

Moreover, it is also a bad idea to declare a variable without `extern` in a header (here ex1.h).  That's probably not having the effect that you want.  Variables without `extern` should only be declared in `.c` files.